# why Tempdata lost once read

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, tempdata

I was going through some links and found something new to me,

[DotNetInterviewQuestion](http://www.dotnetinterviewquestions.in/article_confusing-mvc-interview-questions-on-tempdata-peek-and-keep_243.html) 
at question number 3.

> **Does "TempData" preserve data in the next request also?**
>
> "TempData" is available through out for the current request and in the
>   subsequent request it's available depending on whether "TempData" is
>   read or not.
>
> So if "TempData" is once read it will not be available in the
>   subsequent request.

my question is if `TempData` uses `session` internally ,then why this was done to `TempData`,why isn't it left like `session`?

when Each visitor has its own `session collection` which is created on first request and destroyed when `session expires`,then why it differs in `TempData`!!

i dont  want to know answer about `session vs tempdata` ?all i want why Tempdata has variation if it use session internally,becuase either built in .net must clears the session , so why .net added this features of tempdata,albit it can be done with existing session.

Comment: Obviously because this data is only needed after a redirect and can then be disposed, saving memory.

Comment: My understanding is that it was designed for temporary data (as the name suggests) such as adding a 'success' message when you rediret from a post method to a details view. It means you do not have to manually remove the session variable each time.

Comment: my question raises different issue?,nor i want to know answer about session vs tempdata?all i want why Tempdata has variation if it use session internally @D Stanley

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes i agree, but i found something new there..it persists many redirects until it is read.!

Comment: It IS a session which you use for a specific case. What do you not understand about that?

Comment: @ShekharPankaj, Yes that correct, because its the act of reading it that cause it to also be removed from Session (unless you use `Keep` or `Peek`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes then why to remove it?this is my question ?what benefits does it makes?

Comment: Did you read my answer or the link above, where it's fully explained??

Comment: @ShekharPankaj, So you don't have to keep manually removing it from session when its finished with - it just simplifies the code.

Comment: @L-Three i can't find   answer to this question by you ,and i am reading to links above,but i didn't got what i am looking for?, i am thinking how it benefits over session when it have redirection to single redirects or once read,or usinf  `keep` . there should be option to set number of redirects or something. suppose i want 3 redirects to have same messsage, i need to set it again,why?then whats its advantage?

Comment: As already said a lot of times, you use it to persist data across 1 redirect.

Comment: @ShekharPankaj, you seem to be ignoring the key concept that its **Temp** (orary)Data. Its designed to be read once and disposed - that what is designed for. If you don't want that, then don't use it.

Comment: hmm,i am sensing things up,,but guyz this question isnt duplicate,why marked as duplicate?

Comment: Because it's a duplicate and it's explained in the other answer.